# Подключение к сокету

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket

Возникла необходимость подключаться к серверу по вебсокету. И вот проблема в том что я незнаю в каком месте лучше сделать подключение, сейчас сделал в App.js, но вот как сделать чтобы когда приходит сообщение из сервера, данные шли к компонентам, или как управлять этими компонентами(что-то менять\добавлять) из App.js